# Breeze.js - getting error trying to use "any" operator - error: Unable to get value of the property 'isAnonymous': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, sql, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I am trying to use the "any" operator in Breeze to query a many table and I am getting the following error - TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'isAnonymous': object is null or undefined

The only stackoverflow question I can find that seems related is this one, but there is no solution to the isAnonymous issue because the poster did not provide more code:

[breeze projection : error selecting non scalar navigation properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531964/breeze-projection-error-selecting-non-scalar-navigation-properties)

I am using Breeze 1.4.11 with
Entity Framework 5

The query I am trying to run is

```
var getEntities = function (entitiesObservable) {
    var whereClause = "";

    whereClause = Predicate.create("t_entity_nm", "any", "frst_nm", "startsWith", "Frank");

    var query = EntityQuery.from("Entities")
                           .where(whereClause)
                           .expand("t_entity_nm");

    $('#loading-indicator').show();
    return manager.executeQuery(query)
                  .then(querySucceeded)
                  .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        $('#loading-indicator').hide();
        if (entitiesObservable) {
            entitiesObservable(data.results);
        }
        log("Retrieved [Entities] from remote data source", data, true);
    }
};
```

`t_entity` joins to `t_entity_nm` on `entity_sys_key_id`...they are views...here are the view definitions

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[t_entity]
(     [entity_sys_key_id]
    , [pers_flag]
    , [dob_dt]
    , [birth_plc]
    , [sin]
    , [hsn]
    , [drv_lcnc_num]
    , [ap_vndr_num]
    , [ar_cstmr_num]
    , [sec_grp_sys_key_id]
    , [actv_flag]
    , [log_eff_dt]
    , [log_can_dt]
    , [log_upd_by]
    , [sys_del_flag]
    , [sys_ts] 
)
AS
SELECT 
      [entity_sys_key_id]
    , [pers_flag]
    , [dob_dt]
    , [birth_plc]
    , [sin]
    , [hsn]
    , [drv_lcnc_num]
    , [ap_vndr_num]
    , [ar_cstmr_num]
    , [sec_grp_sys_key_id]
    , [actv_flag]
    , [log_eff_dt]
    , [log_can_dt]
    , [log_upd_by]
    , [sys_del_flag]
    , [sys_ts] 
FROM [CMN_DEV].[dbo].[t_entity]

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[t_entity_nm] 
(
      [entity_nm_sys_key_id]
    , [entity_sys_key_id]
    , [entity_nm_typ_cd]
    , [saltn_cd]
    , [frst_nm]
    , [mid_nm]
    , [last_nm]
    , [firm_nm]
    , [nysiis_key]
    , [prmy_flag]
    , [sec_grp_sys_key_id]
    , [log_eff_dt]
    , [log_can_dt]
    , [log_upd_by]
    , [sys_del_flag]
    , [sys_ts] 
)
AS 
SELECT 
      [entity_nm_sys_key_id]
    , [entity_sys_key_id]
    , [entity_nm_typ_cd]
    , [saltn_cd]
    , [frst_nm]
    , [mid_nm]
    , [last_nm]
    , [firm_nm]
    , [nysiis_key]
    , [prmy_flag]
    , [sec_grp_sys_key_id]
    , [log_eff_dt]
    , [log_can_dt]
    , [log_upd_by]
    , [sys_del_flag]
    , [sys_ts] 
FROM [CMN_DEV].[dbo].[t_entity_nm]
```

The Breeze Controller looks like this:

```
namespace MarketingPromotions.Controllers
{
    [BreezeController(MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 2)]
    public class BreezeController : ApiController
    {

    readonly EFContextProvider<OASIS_DEVEntities> _contextProvider =
            new EFContextProvider<OASIS_DEVEntities>();

        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Metadata();
        }
        #endregion

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<t_entity> Entities()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.t_entity;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<t_entity_nm> EntityNames()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.t_entity_nm;
        }
}
```

The code where it is breaking is in breeze.debug.js on the line ->

```
if (entityType.isAnonymous) return;
```

where "this" is the frst_nm field in the following code snippet from breeze.debug.js:

```
proto._validate = function(entityType) {
        // will throw if not found;
        if (this.isValidated) return;            
        this.isValidated = true;
        if (this.propertyPath) {
            if (entityType.isAnonymous) return;
            var prop = entityType.getProperty(this.propertyPath, true);
            if (!prop) {
                var msg = __formatString("Unable to resolve propertyPath.  EntityType: '%1'   PropertyPath: '%2'", entityType.name, this.propertyPath);
                throw new Error(msg);
            }
            if (prop.isDataProperty) {
                this.dataType = prop.dataType;
            } else {
                this.dataType = prop.entityType;
            }
        } else if (this.fnNodes) {
            this.fnNodes.forEach(function(node) {
                node._validate(entityType);
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried executing your query, ( as it should be translated), directly against EF to determine if the query itself works.

Comment: I tried this at your suggestion and it did work            [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<t_entity> EntitiesByName()
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<t_entity> query = _contextProvider.Context.t_entity;
            query = query.Include("t_entity_nm");
            return query.Where(e => e.t_entity_nm.Any(en => en.frst_nm.StartsWith("Frank")));
        }     and then I saw your other comment about resource name/entity type mapping and that fixed it.

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered?   ( so I can take this one off my list :)

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for your speedy help!  I was just preparing a comment to put under the real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a resource name issue.  My guess is that you have not established a resource name/entity type mapping.

Take a look at these links:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-result-debugging

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_setEntityTypeForResourceName

and this one: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-locally 
under the subtopic: **Resources names are not EntityType names**

Comment: Resources names are not EntityType names was exactly my problem.  The Resource in my case is Entities and EntityType is t_entity  
When I add toType(“t_entity”) to the query, it works  
    var query = EntityQuery.from("Entities").toType("t_entity")  
        .where(whereClause)  
        .expand("t_entity_nm"); 
I am going to try setting entity type in metadatastore  
    var metadataStore = manager.metadataStore;  
    metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Speakers', 'Person');  
in my case  
    metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Entities', 't_entity');  
Thanks!

Comment: I ended up creating a function
    `function mapEntityTypesToResourceNames() {
        var store = datacontext.manager.metadataStore;
         store.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Entities', 't_entity');
        }`  
that I call in shell.js (I am using hot towel with durandal) in the boot method that is the method called after the primeData promise returns in the activate method.`function activate() {
          return datacontext.primeData()
                .then(boot)
                .fail(failedInitialization);
            return boot();
        }`

Comment: We have considered making that a standard option. You might vote for that on User Voice